# How to stretch a specific row in a GridPane to fit the nodes in a single pane?

Tags: javafx

I am making a calendar app and want the ability to add multiple events to a single day. Currently, when I do this, the node stretches to fit the events. I want the whole row to stretch. Visually, this is what happens:

[image]

And this is what I want to happen:

[image]

I have done research and looked at the JavaFX API and am still unsure of how to do this. I am not asking for a code solution, just to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: hgrow always. It's hard to help without knowing exactly what you are doing

Comment: How are you doing each row? For the events inside a day, you should be able to set hgrow to always.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Hi! I have a GridPane inside of a ScrollPane. Each position of the gridpane has a VBox in it. All of these are of the same size initially. The first element of the VBox is the day number, as you can see in the picture. Each time the user adds an event to the day, a label is created an added to the VBox. Here you can see I have 3 labels, and it has caused that specific pane to stretch vertically. I would like to stretch the whole row instead. I have not set up any constraint rules or anything yet.

Comment: You should put your VBox in a scroll pane instead of letting the GridPane row grow. Just my opinion.

Comment: something like VBox -> first line for date. Second Line Scroll pane. Inside scroll pane put the vbox that you use to keep up with events.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I see what you mean. I would implement it that way, but I wouldn't want to hide events so that the user has to go looking for them

Comment: Take a look at out look or some other popular calendar to see how the handle many events.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your label problem.

```
yourLabelName.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```